# Its possible to remove files from data lake using data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Its possible remove files from datalake using data factory?
Its very dificult to do that, i m stuck at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to delete a file using Data Factory. I found that the main purpose of Data Factory is ETL orchestration.

If you are familiar with .NET/Java coding, I would suggest you to create an Azure Function that will be called from ADF and it will delete a file. Azure Functions are now supported in ADF (don't need to use HTTP trigger/web component)

There is an SDK for File operation on Data Lake, and it contains method Delete, that deletes a file from Data Lake Store.
Take a look on this docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk#see-also

Delete method: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.delete?view=azure-dotnet

You can pass path to the file as a request parameter/header whatever you feel comfortable from ADF to Azure Function.
Hope this suggestion can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have is create an Azure Batch to do that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/

You can create an application that remove the files and call it from data factory.
You can pass the files as parameteres too.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.